# C++: Calling private function in a class from the public section of that class

Tags: c++, class, function

If I were to make a class and place several functions into the private section, how would I call the functions from the public section of the same class?
Example:

```
class calculator{
public: //What would go here

private:
    float calculate(float x, char y, float z){
        float answer;

        switch (y){

          case '+':
            answer = x + z;
            break;

          case '-':
            answer = x - z;
            break;

          case '/':
            answer = x / z;
            break;

          case '*':
            answer = x * z;
            break;

          default:
            return(0);
        }
        cout <<"= "; return answer;
    }

    void main(){
        float num1;
        float num2;
        char aOp;
        system("CLS");
        cout << ">> "; cin >> num1 >> aOp >> num2;
        cout << calculate(num1, aOp, num2) << endl << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your `void(!) main()` is a `private` member function(!) of your class?

Comment: main can be of void type

Comment: @cf16 not if it is a standards conformant `main` function.

Comment: he doesn't say it is any_type_main function, he asks how call function

Comment: @juanchopanza Main() in this example was a mistake and was just meant to help illustrate my question. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes. Yes, this is a pretty simple question that some of us take as obvious as gravity pulling us down but I think back to when I first started programming I was trying to use malloc to allocate memory for C++ classes instead of new (turns out this doesn't work well... at all...). Try to remember when you had 'dumb' questions that were really important to you. The asker clearly put effort into this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just call the private member functions from public ones:

```
class Foo
{
 public:
  void foo() { privateFoo(); }
 private:
  void privateFoo();

};
```

Answer (score 3):

normally as you do now. you are in the same class so you have access to private methods.
just make main public. Also note that main is not a good name for a member function. main is usually reserved for the entry point of the program and must not be in a class.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call the function declared in private, and if you want to call it from anywhere, you have to call a function in the public section(or protected for inherited classes), and from that you have to call this private function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Remember one thing.
A private function can only be called with the help of another function that is a member of the same class. Even an object can not invoke a private function using the dot operator.See this example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class student
{
private:
int m;
void read void //Private function of the class.
public:
void update(void);
void write(void);
};
```

if s1 is an object of the class student then, we would not be able to write this-

```
s1.read(); //it won't work: object can not access private members.
```

but we know we can call read() function with the help of another function of the same class, so we could call it with the help of **update()** function or **write()** function.
So here we call the read() function with the help of the update() function to update the value of m.

```
void student :: update(void)
{
read(); ///simple call ; no object used
}
```

So, here is how you can call a private member function. **Finally here is the full program which update the value of m with the help of update() and read() function. --**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class student
{
int m;
void read()
{
m=5;
cout<<m;
}
public:
void update();
void write();

};
void student :: update()
{
    read();
}
int main()
{
student s1;
s1.update();
return 0;
}
```